# Progress Percentage calculate Sub Percentages

Tags: org-mode

```
* TODO Organize party [50%]
** TODO call people [33%]
   - [ ] Peter
   - [X] Sarah
   - [ ] Sam
** DONE order food
** TODO think about what music to play
** DONE talk to the neighbors
```

is there a way to tell org mode to include the 30% to the overall Organize party header?

2 items done = 50 %
2 items done and one item 33% done = 50% + (25% * 33%)

Comment: Even better would be if we could add an effort estimate to each elementary item and then add the done effort and the estimated effort hierarchically up to the root. Maybe there could be some default effort for items without explicitly defined effort.

Comment: BTW the function that needs to be modified is [`org-update-parent-todo-statistics`](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/org.el#L10404).

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought of.   
Beeing able to give TODO Tasks a specific level of estimated effort would enhance projectmanagement a lot.

Comment: Maybe an enhancement request is in place.

Comment: There are already effort estimates: https://orgmode.org/manual/Effort-estimates.html